# Android context menu on async filled listview

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, android-asynctask

I have a listview which is filled by AsyncTask and I am trying to create a context menu....

```
@Override
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, 
                                  View v, 
                                  ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);


    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    int position = info.position;
    ChannelShowItem myItem = (ChannelShowItem) aa.getItem(position);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("TEST");
    menu.add(0, 1,  Menu.NONE, R.string.remove_item);
}
```

I can run the app, but context menu is never created... On the other hand I tried to use the same code on listview which isn't filled by a AsyncTask and it worked OK...

I believe that I have to create context menu when data is filled, but I don't know how... Thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overriding `onPrepareContextMenu`, this method is called every time the context menu is opening. Hope this helps.

Comment: hmmm ... how to ... from asyncTask?

Comment: OK, then you should call registerForContextMenu(getListView()); after you've filled your list. And you should override onPrepareContextMenu, as I've said, to make your menu refresh every time you open it.

Comment: Yeah that is what I wanted... It is strange ... Basically with no major changes and with restarting Eclipse now it works! Thanks a lot!